# SQL query select return result not in ONE table

Tags: mysql, sql, python-3.x

Say I have a table `people` with a `name` field.
In that table are 3 rows with names: `Steve, Mark, Ricky`

Then I have a list of names: `[Shane, Ricky, Mark]`

I want to execute one query that will return the values that aren't already in the table.

I know I can do this with the following:

```
names = [Shane, Ricky, Mark]

for name in names:
    sql = '''SELECT * FROM people WHERE name=%s'''
    db.execute(sql, args=name)
    results = db.fetchall()
    
    # If no results are returned for a name 
    # this means the name isn't already in the table.
    if not results:
        print(name) # This would return 'Shane' as it's not already in the table.
```

Is there a way I could do this more efficiently with one SQL statement, rather than looping over each name in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the SQL `IN` operator, selecting the values already in the table;

`SELECT * FROM people WHERE name IN (...your values...)`

and then finding the difference between the two lists:

`not_in_db = list(set(names).difference(set(results)))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use: `SELECT * FROM people WHERE name NOT IN(...)`

Comment: I agree with the use of IN, but the question is other way 'round, he wants to get the names that are not in the table already.

Comment: Yes, when he supplies the values, it will definitely give him the value that are not in database

Answer (score 0):

UNTESTED:

Generate the list as a table (t1) and then return from that generated table, those values not in your people table.

The issue is a database can't return values that don't exist.  So we first create a temporary table with your values so they exist and can be returned.
Then we rub it up against the people table to find those that don't exist; thus allowing us to return those names not in people table.

```
SELECT *
FROM (values row('Shane'),
             row('Ricky'),
             row('Mark')) t1 (Name)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM people P where P.Name = T1.Name)
```

or perhaps:  (I don't think you need to specify a table in mySQL if I recall.)

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT 'Shane' as Name UNION ALL
      SELECT 'Ricky' UNION ALL
      SELECT 'Mark') t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM people P where P.Name = T1.Name)
```

So the above is the SQL for your `sql =` statement

Though in both cases we should specify data type for Name be it varchar, nvarchar and length...